# Why am I not seeing records that are ostensibly inserted?

Tags: apex, soql, dml

We're creating sample data when we spin up a scratch org, and we have just added a new join table between two existing tables, but the records don't seem to be actually inserting, although the code I'm executing reports that it is.

I took out the code from the class and tried troubleshooting it with anonymous Apex. Here's the code I'm working with right now (note that in the Apex class I'm not retrieving the records like this, but using them as stored instance variables, i.e., `this.loans`, `this.scenarios`, `this.scenarioIncomes`):

```
List<ScenarioIncome__c> scenarioIncomes = new List<ScenarioIncome__c>();
for (Loan__c loan : [SELECT Id FROM Loan__c]) {
    for (Scenario__c scenario : [SELECT Id, Loan__c FROM Scenario__c]) {
        if (scenario.Loan__c == loan.Id) {
            for (Income__c income : [SELECT Id, Borrower__r.Loan__c FROM Income__c]) {
                if (income.Borrower__r.Loan__c == loan.Id) {
                    scenarioIncomes.add(
                        new ScenarioIncome__c(
                            Income__c = income.Id,
                            Scenario__c = scenario.Id
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
System.debug(scenarioIncomes);
insert scenarioIncomes;
System.debug(scenarioIncomes);
scenarioIncomes = [SELECT Id, Scenario__c, Income__c FROM ScenarioIncome__c];
System.debug( scenarioIncomes);
System.debug('inserted');
```

Using VS Code I select this Apex and execute it anonymously. The `System.debug`s output the following.

```
09:52:28.29 (185769051)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|(ScenarioIncome__c:{Income__c=a0401000002AdGYAA0,
    Scenario__c=a0M01000007iYlJEAU},ScenarioIncome__c:{Income__c=a0401000002AdGZAA0...
09:52:28.29 (259686097)|USER_DEBUG|[20]|DEBUG|(ScenarioIncome__c:{Income__c=a0401000002AdGYAA0,
    Scenario__c=a0M01000007iYlJEAU, Id=a0K01000005Jy7GEAS}, ScenarioIncome__c: ...
09:52:28.29 (279098380)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|(ScenarioIncome__c:{Id=a0K01000005Jy6SEAS,
    Scenario__c=a0M01000007iYlJEAU, Income__c=a0401000002AdGYAA0}, ...
09:52:28.29 (279143483)|USER_DEBUG|[23]|DEBUG|inserted
```

So, debugging the variable before insert lacks the `Id`s, after shows them, and retrieving them with a query is successful. All indications here are that the records were successfully inserted, and the `"inserted"` line proves there wasn't an error that prevented any execution.

But then I go the org, look at the "All Scenario Incomes" view, and see no records. OK, I execute `sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id, Scenario__c, Income__c FROM ScenarioIncome__c"` in the terminal. No records. I try `sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id, Scenario__c, Income__c FROM ScenarioIncome__c WHERE Id = 'a0K01000005Jy7GEAS'"`, using the Id from the second `System.debug(scenarioIncomes)`. No records.

What is going on here? Why would the anonymous Apex show inserted records but executing SOQL and the web UI does not?

Note that if I use the web UI to create a `ScenarioIncome__c` record, it works and the SOQL shows it.

Clues:

- The relationships from `ScenarioIncome__c` to the parent tables are both master/detail relationships.
- The user I'm logged into on the web UI is "User User."
- I've used `sfdx force:org:list` to confirm that the default org has the same username as "User User" using "Setup."
- I've added `CreatedBy.Name` to the query in the anonymous Apex, and it returns `CreatedById` instead.
- When I search for that Id in the `User` table, no records are returned.
- The Id returned by the anonymous Apex and that returned by querying the Id of "User User" have different first five characters, indicating they're on different orgs (right?).
- But the org list username and User User's email address match.

I guess it's possible that I'm working with one org in VS Code and another in the web UI, but I don't see how that's possible. However, executing the above code in the dev console instead of VS Code works.

So I guess I *must* be working in two orgs. So the question has moved to, how is that possible given the above?

Comment: Does your user have at least read access to all three types of object, is the junction object using master detail relationships and do you have appropriate sharing?

Comment: Both relationships are master/detail from `ScenarioIncome__c` to `Scenario__c` and `Income__c`, mostly for the auto-delete feature. Having a join record doesn't make sense if one of the parents is deleted. The user has all permissions for all three tables.

Comment: And the sharing? Are you accessing the org using the same user as that used to insert the data?

Comment: @PhilW, I really appreciate your help on this. I've expanded the question with additional knowledge from some tests.

Comment: Try opening the web UI using `sfdx force:org:open` from within VSCode.

Comment: I did that just now, and it opened the same org that using the command pallet opened. That command is also in my bash script that I use to create scratch orgs and populate them with data.

Comment: Have you got an override in VSCode for the default scratch org?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to do that. :) I'm starting over with a new org and a VS Code relaunch, maybe it's just a glitch of some sort.

Comment: Well, @PhilW, it's definitely executing on a different org than what opens via the `sfdx` command. No idea why. But the code above works when I use the dev console. And the immediate goal was to get some accurate data on there so I can test the trigger this is all for testing. I'll try to come back here when I have time and post a question about how anonymous Apex is executing on an org other than the default when I'm not specifying a user name in the command. I did see it was executing on the previous scratch org I had created (by the org Ids).

Comment: You can check the CLI default using `sfdx force:org:list` and check VSCode as covered [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/default-org).

Comment: I had done that. SFDX was reporting as the default org the one that opened, which makes sense. There seems to have been a disparity between which org was default when I opened it and which was default when I executed anonymous Apex.

Comment: That is odd. I don't use VSCode myself so will have to leave it to others to suggest a reason.